# The speed control switch on ceiling fan and needed to be replaced & disintegrated on removal. I cannot match the wires with the right terminals

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

The fan has yellow, red, black & blue wires. The switch was a KTE E87438 3089 pull-chain switch & I purchased a replacement. I no longer have the fan's manufacturer, but I need to know whether or not your wiring diagram might work for me.

Comment: There's nothing on the fan itself indicating a manufacturer and/or model? Are you in the US or somewhere else? In my experience (in the US), usually fans are wired with white (neutral for the fan & lights), bare/green (ground for both), black (switched hot for the fan) and blue (switched hot for the lights). Your fan with yellow & red is not-US or a very odd duck.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find on the switch it is a single pole 4 position where one is off. Turn the power off and use an ohmmeter, you will have continuity between three of the leads, the one remaining is your power feed.  There are many sources available on line where you can get a replacement High, Med, Low, and off pull chain switch. If you want to know which winding is which connect one of the three windings to the power and turn on, the fan should run, determine its speed. then turn the power back off. Do the same with the remaining two. At that point you know which color is for which speed. You can then match that up to your replacement switch. If you get the order wrong it should not hurt anything, the fan simply will not sequence in the correctly as you switch speeds. If you can find a switch that matches you simply place the same colors to the same terminals.  Try this link for more information on selecting the switch: https://www.ceilingfanswitch.com/ceiling-fan-switch-guide/

Comment: I already have the exact replacement speed switch. With that I need to know which colour leads connect with the numbered terminals on the switch. E.g. which lead is "off"?